# Quantize vs Discrete

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in definition between the word "quantize" and "discrete"?

For example, the Oxford definitions are:

**Quantize**:

> ... restrict the number of possible values of (a quantity) or states of (a system) so that certain variables can assume only certain discrete magnitudes

**Discrete**:

> Individually separate and distinct

Is it that "quantize" must refer to values while "discrete" does not?

Comment: There is a word derived from discrete that has in some but not all situations a meaning similar to quantize, namely discretize. It is commonly used in the mathematical and physical literature, but has not yet made it into the popular dictionaries. It can be found here, though: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretize

Comment: Why was this post down voted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, the *difference* is that **quantization** (infinitive is *to quantize*) is a verb. It is the act of organizing into discrete values. **Discrete** is an adjective. It describes the state that the values are in after they are *quantized*.

Comment: I suppose `quantize` could be turned into an adjective synonymous with `discrete`: `quantized`.

Comment: @Barmar: I suppose it could. But usually *quantized* means that something was originally continuous, and has been made discrete. The adjective *discrete* carries no such connotation.

Answer (score 0):

In electronics, `quantization` refers to a process in which analog signal is converted to digital one by assigning values based on electrical current strength measurement being in a specific range. Values obtained in this process are discrete, because they are `individually separate and distinct`, as in definition.